# C# new Task clarification

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, multitasking

After reading multiple articles issued at different years I got more confused then before.

I wanted to know how to make sure the tasks I create will run on multiple cores ??

The function below has to handle lots of files being uploaded to the server :

```
private void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

        var SyncTask = new Task(() => 
        {

            //DO A LOT OF WORK HERE
        });

        SyncTask.Start();

    }
```

I just couldn't find a straight answer if this is the way to go on 4.7.2 .NET framework or not ?

Comment: The recommended way is to use `Task.Run`. See also the [Task constructor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task__ctor_System_Action_) which states that using the constructor is only for advanced scenarios when you need to separate Task setup and kick-off, which is extremely rare. Also you should await your task.

Comment: Tasks will run on thread pool, it manages how to run the task and which thread to use

Comment: Ok sure, buy will the thread pool assign the tasks to run on multiple cores if needed ?

Comment: Usually using `Task.Run()` you may not care about cores. But you may set LongRunning option to force new Thread creation. And there's an option to consider of using `async`/`await`. It's the way to do the job with saving thread resources. And yes, it may use multiple cores. For the way to go: go to the .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Thanks , I tested Task.Run() with windows recourse monitor and I could clearly see that the work load was spread among all cores equally by using Task.Run()

Answer (score 0):

The task itself will run on a **single** core.  If you want "//DO A LOT OF WORK HERE" to run on multiple cores, you need to parallelize that work either by spawning tasks from this task (see also [Child tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/attached-and-detached-child-tasks), or by using the simpler `Parallel`.

Otherwise, whether you use your approach or just `Task.Run(..)` it doesn't quite matter in your case.

**EDIT**  See this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/), it explains nicely the difference.